# How To Change Oracle Apex Chart Type Programmatically

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a simple **Chart Region:**  *with*

`Static ID: Chart_Region`

**Attribute** `Type: Pie`

**Chart Serie: Salary Chart**

Sql Query:  `Select Department_id, Sum(Salary) Sum_Sal From Employees Group by Department_Id;`

Column Mapping: `Label: Department_ID` , `Value: Sum_Sal` and `Static ID: Chart_ID`

Simply I want to enable the end user to change the Chart `Type: Pie` to `Type: Bar` at the runtime (using toggle buttons that I have added).
Any Idea please !.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to render both charts but display one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it with Javascript like so:

```
apex.region('Chart_Region').widget.ojChart({type:'bar'});
```

and

```
apex.region('Chart_Region').widget.ojChart({type:'pie'});
```

available values for type are:

```
area, bar, boxPlot, bubble, combo, funnel, line, lineWithArea, pie, pyramid, scatter, stock
```

Comment: the JavaScript code did you associated to a button ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Yes, using "Execute Javascript" dynamic action.